# How to Change Line to Specific Color in RichTextBox Based on Sub

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have created a method where in the code you can write `WritetoConsole(SomeString, LogType)` but when the LogType is activated, (A different color per type of log), it changes the entire color of the richtextbox, not the actual line that was entered.

It's supposed to be a custom console in a WinForm Application. So Basically Whatever is inputed into `Message` is what should be written to the console, dependingon LogitType. But I don't want it to change the entire RichTextBox's text color. I just want the specific line that's being entered

```
Dim NewLine As String = (Chr(13))
Dim LogType As LogerType
''' <summary>
''' Writes a Message to the Homework Helper Console
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Message">The Message to Display to Console</param>
''' <param name="LogitType">The Type of Message to Display to Console</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub WritetoConsole(Message As String, LogitType As Color)
    LogerType.Normal = Color.White
    LogerType.Warning = Color.Yellow
    LogerType.ErrorMessage = Color.Maroon
    LogerType.Homework = Color.Green
    LogerType.Project = Color.Red
    LogerType.Test = Color.RosyBrown
    If Message = Nothing Then
        rtbInput.AppendText(Errors(3))
    Else
        rtbInput.AppendText(NewLine & Message)
    End If


    If LogitType = LogerType.Normal Then
        rtbInput.ForeColor = LogerType.Normal
    ElseIf LogitType = LogerType.Warning Then
        rtbInput.ForeColor = LogerType.Warning
    ElseIf LogitType = LogerType.ErrorMessage Then
        rtbInput.ForeColor = LogerType.ErrorMessage
    ElseIf LogitType = LogerType.Homework Then
        rtbInput.ForeColor = LogerType.Homework
    ElseIf LogitType = LogerType.Project Then
        rtbInput.ForeColor = LogerType.Project
    ElseIf LogitType = LogerType.Test Then
        rtbInput.ForeColor = LogerType.Test
    ElseIf LogitType = Nothing Then
        WritetoConsole((Errors(3)), LogerType.ErrorMessage)
    Else
        MsgBox(Errors(4))
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your not writing to a console your writing to a richtextbox, very different.

Comment: Also you have declared a variable logtype as logertype but dont use it. I would put those in an enum and use them that way.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR rtbInput.AppendText(NewLine & Message) Adds to the RichTextBox, making it seem like a console... Making the sub procedure WritetoConsole(Message As String, LogitType As Color) Enables it to Work Like as a console using WritetoConsole(Message, LogitType)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `rtbInput.SelectionColor` not `rtbInput.ForeColor`. So:

```
Public Sub WritetoConsole(Message As String, LogitType As Color)
    LogerType.Normal = Color.White
    LogerType.Warning = Color.Yellow
    LogerType.ErrorMessage = Color.Maroon
    LogerType.Homework = Color.Green
    LogerType.Project = Color.Red
    LogerType.Test = Color.RosyBrown

    rtbInput.Select(rtbInput.TextLength, 0)

    If LogitType = LogerType.Normal Then
        rtbInput.SelectionColor= LogerType.Normal
    ElseIf LogitType = LogerType.Warning Then
        rtbInput.SelectionColor= LogerType.Warning
    ElseIf LogitType = LogerType.ErrorMessage Then
        rtbInput.SelectionColor= LogerType.ErrorMessage
    ElseIf LogitType = LogerType.Homework Then
        rtbInput.SelectionColor= LogerType.Homework
    ElseIf LogitType = LogerType.Project Then
        rtbInput.SelectionColor= LogerType.Project
    ElseIf LogitType = LogerType.Test Then
        rtbInput.SelectionColor= LogerType.Test
    ElseIf LogitType = Nothing Then
        WritetoConsole((Errors(3)), LogerType.ErrorMessage)
    Else
        MsgBox(Errors(4))
    End If

   If Message = Nothing Then
        rtbInput.AppendText(Errors(3))
    Else
        rtbInput.AppendText(NewLine & Message)
    End If

End Sub
```

valter

Comment: That will still select all text in the box not just what he needs

Comment: Ok and when he calls this again it will select the whole length of the text inside it, did you test it, i did and doesnt work, please make sure to test before you post a solution

Comment: Look at the screen shot, it says for itself buddy. I have wrote a function that does this a hundred times better. Actually just helped a guy two days ago with it.

Comment: Yes, and by that code, you are selecting the whole text from where it was found and down. For ex: look at the screenshot noticed how it found the string I said, well it kept highlighting everything else and down.

Comment: Exactly what u did and i can tell u where its wrong in your code, specifically when you do the select what are you selecting, thats right the whole text from the box not the message that was passed in. Show me where your selecting the massage at?

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR **I AM MOVING THE INSERTION POINT TO THE END** with `rtbInput.Select(rtbInput.TextLength, 0)` and **then** append the text. It is crystal clear. If you can not understand is your problem